# How to see console.log outputs in capacitor v3 live reload

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, livereload

Before the Capacitor v3 update I was able to run the command

```
ionic cap run ios -l --external
```

and it would open the xcode from where I used to select my simulator and run the app. I was able to see all the console.log outputs in the xcode window.

However now with v3 update the same command does not open the IDE. Instead it asks for simulator options. When I select one it opens the simulator directly without the IDE. In this case where can I see the console.log outputs?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new default behaviour of Capacitor v3. You can add the `--open` option to open XCode like it did in v2:

```
ionic cap run ios -l --external --open
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-run